Find organizational unit / orgUnitPath of current non-admin user
Is there a way to find the organization of the current user in a Google Apps Script without granting the user itself any special / admin permissions in the Workspace?
For background, the organizational unit path in Google Workspace is e.g. /Colleges/Comparative Irrelevance/Tetrapyloctomy for a user in the Tetrapylectomy organization which is a sub-organization of Comparative Irrelevance, etc. Admins can see this orgUnitPath, and  can retrieve it from Google Apps Scripts using AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail).orgUnitPath. My add-on needs to know the organization since certain features should only be available to certain organizations.
When I try
const userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
const user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);

with an admin user, I can get the orgUnitPath from user.
But with a regular non-admin user, I get
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.users.get failed with error: Not Authorized to access this resource/api

My addon only needs the organization, no other information for the user.
I see there is
AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail, {viewType:'domain_public'});

but that doesn't include any organization info. (Are Google Workspace users really not meant to see what part of the organizational hierarchy they've been assigned? Very kafkaesque.)

Things I have tried:
Service Account and Domain-Wide Delegation
I saw from apps-script-oauth2/samples/CloudIAPServiceAccount that one can impersonate an admin-user using a Service Account added to the add-on project. I tried this, it "works", but that means 1. the workspace admin needs to add this Service Account with Domain-Wide Delegation to the workspace, and 2. the add-on needs to know the email of some admin user to impersonate. There has to be a simpler way.

I also tried making a Google Webapp which does the lookup via Service Account impersonation so the Google Docs Addon doesn't have to know the admin email, but if the Webapp and Addon are both running the same code (and are developed and deployed by the same Google user) and all the lookups happen server-side anyway, then I don't see any gain from the added complexity. (The same set of permissions and configurations have to be granted to the same set of code, except the code is now spread across two projects which need to communicate securely with each other.)

Custom User Fields
One can add Custom User Fields which are readable with viewType:'domain_public'. But then the workspace admin has to somehow keep these fields up-to-date with the organizations. The synchronization can be scripted, but that script still needs to run every so often. I'd prefer a solution that doesn't involve maintenance work for the Workspace admin.

Not familiar with org unit path, but You can create a webapp api to execute as admin to only give out this info upon http post

@TheMaster This would require specifying some admin user to run the webapp api as? Would it have to run under the workspace, or can one use Domain-Wide Delegation? Could the api at least be restricted to only allow returning the orgName of the user requesting to know their orgName and no other info? (I don't like how AdminDirectory.Users.get potentially allows getting info for other users.)

Not sure about the use case:whether you're working on a public addon or just within one workspace. Webapp needs to be deployed by a admin within that organisation to execute as "Me"(the admin). In essence, the code of the webapp runs as the admin and only returns what you specify. There are issues with authentication however. How would the webapp code know who executes it's code? The outside script needs to send the user email along with a identitytoken  or a access token to prove that it's their email.

The token needs to be checked on the webapp side. You also need to handle all authorisation in between calls and choose a suitable protocol. https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script?tab=readme-ov-file#4-client-users-access-to-web-apps-using-curl-google-apps-script-and-so-on-which-dont-use-browser  A bit more complicated than service accounts, but the  clear advantage over service accounts/domain wide delegation is you limit what other users can get through your own webapp api(because you control it).

Phew, this was not easy :) I've tried making a webapp, and it's simple enough to look up the orgUnitPath via a Service Account from the webapp, but if I deploy it to "anyone with a google account", I'm not able to use it from the addon even with Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(), and even though I can run it that way from the same user in a script; it just redirects me to the signin page.

and if I deploy it to anyone anonymously I could call it like "?token="+ScriptApp.getIdentityToken(); but then how do I verify that in the Google Apps Script? I can find the email from the token, but I can't know that it's from the right user without verifying the sig. For some reason there doesn't seem to be a JWT.verify function builtin to Google Apps Script, and the libraries I've tried all fail expecting window or navigator to be available. How did you do verification @TheMaster ?

Does the access token have drive scope? That is needed. JWT verify is indeed not available, but Google has a test api to  verify the jwt(so a http call should work, though it isn't recommended by Google themselves). (If you're willing to go down the rabbit hole, jwt verify  library that works in nodejs should theoretically work here - you need to bundle it as one file and workout minor dependencies)

Yeah I found out the hard way about drive scope. And I saw the test api, tough I'm afraid of being throttled in production :) I even tried gas-webpack-plugin but eventually gave up on that. OTOH, I'm starting to think a webapp doesn't actually give me much since I end up running the same code there as the plugin backend would anyway so it's just another back-and-forth to get the same info (and both plugin and webapp would be running under the same project). I could see the point in webapp here if plugin and webapp were owned by different entities though.

The webapp should be a different project with only admin  access. About jwt verify, in theory, you could use a python/rust/c/asm library using wasm in apps script: https://justin.poehnelt.com/posts/apps-script-wasm// But if you want to skip apps script altogether,  Google cloud functions are an alternative.

I don't believe The same set of permissions and configurations have to be granted to the same set of code. For example, the webapp project only needs Admin.Users scope... the calling project needs drive scope and so on.

@TheMaster Yes, the individual pieces have non-overlapping sets of permissions, but the code considered as a whole (the sum of the projects) needs the same set of permissions. Splitting responsibilities might make auditing easier in one way (we then know that the addon code can't look at admindir directly), but it also gets worse since now the webapp needs to verify auth where before there was no such need (and rely on third party deps instead of builtins etc.).
